# Feynman diagrams and pair creation/annihilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, feynman-diagrams

I'm trying to make sense of QFT (I am a mathematician). I have absorbed "from the ether" the following physical interpretation of Feynman diagrams in the Hamiltonian picture, which I really like, but which I have not seen written anywhere explicitly and I suspect it might be wrong. Is it correct, or fixable?

Here's the picture I have in my head. Suppose you have a boson in a bound state, $|+\rangle,$ which has an antiparticle $|-\rangle.$ A multiparticle state can be described as a pair of integers, $|+\cdots +, -\cdots -\rangle = \, : |m\,,n\rangle$ (consisting of $m$ particles and $n$ antiparticles), a basis vector in a Fock space. Now we can identify $|m, n\rangle$ formally with the monomial $z^m \bar{z}^n,$ where $z$ and $\bar{z}$ are conjugate variables. We have a pair of creation operators $z, \bar{z}$ and a pair of annihilation operators $\partial, \bar{\partial},$ which raise and lower particle number (here I'm ignoring some normalization conventions). The antiparticle convention says that the operator $z$ is conjugate to $\bar{\partial}$ and $\bar{z}$ is conjugate to $\partial,$ so when you write down a Hermitian operator which creates a particle you're also annihilating an antiparticle.

The "free" Hamiltonian in this system is proportional to $H_{free} := z\partial + \bar{z}\bar{\partial}$ i.e. diagonalized in the $|m,n\rangle$ basis with the energy proportional to the total number of particles. One would like to now perturb it to $H = H_{free}+\epsilon A,$ for $A$ the perturbation term. Moreover, the bound state picture should be interpreted as a free particle in a single momentum mode, and the perturbation can now mix the Fock spaces for these modes. The key point is that when perturbing, one can first solve exactly the quadratic Hamiltonian $H_Q = H_{free}+\epsilon Q,$ where $Q$ is the sum of terms in the perturbation matrix $A$ that are "quadratic", i.e. change the number of particles by at most $2$. For some physical reasons (charge conservation?), we must have $Q$ proportional to $z\bar{z} +\partial\bar{\partial},$ corresponding to some probability of spontaneous particle-antiparticle creation and annihilation.

To perturbatively solve the time evolution equation $U_t = e^{it(H_{free} + \epsilon A)},$ one writes $U_t$ as a power series in $\epsilon$, with the $\epsilon^n$ term naturally decomposing as a sum of directed graphs *with $n$ vertices*, and with each vertex encoding an "event" where some number of particles come in and some (possibly different) number of particles come out (to get the graph, one "labels" the identical particles to keep track of edges: this is allowed so long as they are symmetrized at the end). All the degree-two vertices will be the pair creation and annihilation events encoded by $Q$; as physical considerations preclude valency-one vertices, all other vertices will have degree $3$ or more.

Now my understanding has been that Feynman's contribution is that instead of taking the "unperturbed Hamiltonian" to be $H_{free},$ one instead exactly solves the quadratic Hamiltonian $H_Q = H_{free}+\epsilon Q$ via a propagator, and groups only terms of degree $3$ or higher in the perturbation term.

Then instead of writing $e^{it H}$ as a sum over all directed graphs with edges of valency $\ge 2$, one gets a new sum of pertucbation terms over graphs of vertex degree $\ge 3$. The "new" term corresponding to a (valency $\ge 3$) graph $\Gamma$ will be the sum of all "old" terms corresponding to graphs which are edge subdivisions of $\Gamma$. Since the subdivided edges can "go" both forwards and backwards in time, the graphs indexing in the new sum are no longer naturally directed (or at least the directed structure no longer corresponds to time).

However in practice the quadratic perturbation terms $Q$ seem to be zero! Does this mean that "really" you only get contributions from graphs which go forwards in time, and the whole virtual particle picture is just a formalistic flourish, or is there something here I am missing altogether?

Comment: Perhaps a good book on QFT would help. What you have written here has a speculative nature which is, as far as I know, outside the scope of Physics SE.

Comment: Looks like you are straining to reinvent the [Segal-Bargmann space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal–Bargmann_space) picture of Fock space. Hall's book cited there might please you on it.